# leaflet - divicon - How to hide the default square shadow?

Tags: leaflet, symbology

For example, I write this:

```
L.marker([lat, long], {icon: L.divIcon({html:"China"})}).addTo(map);
```

I checked the documentation:

> By default, it has a 'leaflet-div-icon' CSS class and is styled as a
>   little white square with a shadow.

But how can I change the default style? I try to change the "className", but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [`className`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#icon-classname) option of the [DivIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#divicon) correctly removes the default `leaflet-div-icon` class, hence removes the default styling (white square with black border):

```js
L.marker([lat, long], {
  icon: L.divIcon({
    html: 'Icon text',
    className: 'dummy' // Specify something to get rid of the default class.
  })
}).addTo(map);
```

[image: Screenshot of result of DivIcon with dummy className option]

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ci8hD2x29ocejDEp

Comment: Yes. It works now. But I know the true reason after I contrast my code and yours. Because I loaded `leaflet.marker.highlight.js` which made a little difference. Now I removed it, it can work.